# Tidyverse way to get lm()-residuals using a subset of columns as predictors but keeping all in output

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have some data like this:

```r
dat = tibble(
      var1 = rep(c('A','B'),each=5)
    , var2 = rnorm(10)
    , var3 = rnorm(10)
    , var4 = rnorm(10)
    , var5 = rnorm(10)
)
```

I can get what I want by explicitly naming the columns to be used in the lm formula:

```
dat %>%
    #dat has columns: var1 through var5
    dplyr::group_by(var1) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
        resids = resid(lm( var2 ~ var3 + var4 ))
    )
```

But I actually have many columns in my real data set, and the number and names of the ones I'll be using will vary. I do know the names of the ones I don't want, so I thought this would work:

```r
dat %>%
    #dat has columns: var1 through var5
    dplyr::group_by(var1) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
        resids = resid(lm( 
            formula = var2 ~ .
            , data = . %>% select(-var1, -var5)
     ))
    )
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is `dat`? Could you `dput(dat)` and add to the question?

Comment: @Duck I added code to generate a dummy data set at the beginning.

Comment: @IRTFM because, as stated in the title, I want to retain all original columns in the output, just adding the residuals as a new column.

Comment: Yeah, that works but isn't very tidyverse-esque, in contrast with the accepted answer.

Comment: @IRTFM no error doesn't mean it's right...please check the output of `lm()`. `group_by()` makes no sense after passing to `lm()`, so `var1` is still included in the model and has a  coefficient estimate.

Comment: I didn't think it would produce an estimate for 'var1' since there would be no variance within each subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the special symbol `"."` in `data = . %>% select(-var1, -var5)` is actually the input data which has not been grouped. After `dplyr 1.0.0` this issue has been solved by `cur_data()`, which gives the current data for the current group (exclusing grouping variables).

```
dat %>%
  group_by(var1) %>%
  mutate(
    resids = resid(lm(var2 ~ ., cur_data() %>% select(-var5)))
  )
```

Note that I use `select(-var5)` instead of `select(ivar1, -var5)` because `cur_data()` has excluded grouping variables, i.e. `var1`, so `select(ivar1, -var5)` will get an error:

> Can't subset columns that don't exist.

---

As @IRTFM comments, you can also select variables before passing to `lm`. Remember to use `cur_data()` rather than `"."`.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(var1) %>%
  select(-var5) %>%
  mutate(
    resids = resid(lm(var2 ~ ., cur_data()))
  )
```

Here you still don't need to exclude `var1` in `select()` because grouping variables cannot be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the variables that aren't going to be on the right-hand side of the model, one option is to get those names into a vector and then build the formula for `lm()`.  This means doing an extra step outside your pipe chain.

Building the formula is a relatively common approach for, e.g., making functions for fitting models.  I wrote a blog post to show this approach [here](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2019/06/24/function-for-model-fitting/).

In your case, you can pull the names of the variables you want in the model as a character vector based on the variables you don't want.

```
modvars = dat %>%
     select(-var1, -var5, -var2) %>%
     names()
modvars
[1] "var3" "var4"
```

You can build the formula for model fitting using `as.formula()` after pasting the variables together.  This is what that would look like:

```
as.formula(paste("var2 ~", paste(modvars, collapse = "+") ) )
var2 ~ var3 + var4
```

Even easier is the `reformulate()` approach from the comments thanks to @BenBolker.

```
reformulate(modvars, response = "var2")
var2 ~ var3 + var4
```

You could build this outside your pipe chain or put it directly within the chain.  Here I do the latter.

```
dat %>%
     dplyr::group_by(var1) %>%
     dplyr::mutate(
          resids = resid(lm( 
               formula = reformulate(modvars, response = "var2") )
          )
     )
# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   var1 [2]
   var1     var2    var3    var4    var5 resids
   <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A      0.0792  0.265   0.637  -0.106   0.386
 2 A     -0.845   0.386   1.20    1.55   -0.232
 3 A      0.465   1.12   -0.750   0.726  -0.141
 4 A     -0.365  -1.19    0.174   0.347  -0.126
 5 A      0.395  -0.0515 -0.464  -0.0934  0.112
 6 B     -2.83   -0.0664 -0.0958  0.588  -1.99 
 7 B      0.383   1.16   -0.339   0.492   0.838
 8 B      1.35    0.270   2.40    0.626  -0.512
 9 B      0.620  -1.33    1.32   -0.148   0.688
10 B      0.664  -0.0487  0.426  -0.158   0.973
```

The residuals match your original approach where you wrote the formula out:

```
dat %>%
     #dat has columns: var1 through var5
     dplyr::group_by(var1) %>%
     dplyr::mutate(
          resids = resid(lm( var2 ~ var3 + var4 ))
     )

# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   var1 [2]
   var1     var2    var3    var4    var5 resids
   <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A      0.0792  0.265   0.637  -0.106   0.386
 2 A     -0.845   0.386   1.20    1.55   -0.232
 3 A      0.465   1.12   -0.750   0.726  -0.141
 4 A     -0.365  -1.19    0.174   0.347  -0.126
 5 A      0.395  -0.0515 -0.464  -0.0934  0.112
 6 B     -2.83   -0.0664 -0.0958  0.588  -1.99 
 7 B      0.383   1.16   -0.339   0.492   0.838
 8 B      1.35    0.270   2.40    0.626  -0.512
 9 B      0.620  -1.33    1.32   -0.148   0.688
10 B      0.664  -0.0487  0.426  -0.158   0.973
```

Comment: don't forget `reformulate` ... (`reformulate(modvars, response="var2")`)

Comment: I don't think I've ever used `reformulate()` @BenBolker, which appears to be quite awesome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is not the subsettng but rather the confusion of the `.` in the formula. Is this referring to the variables or to the data.

There are other issues also with regard to this, ie the select. You should do`data = {.}%>%subset(-var1,var5)` and not what you have, or simply do `data = subset(.,-var1,-var5)`. HOw to solve this issue:

**use nest + unnest**

By `nest`ing_by, the grouping variable is automatically removed from the data:

```
dat %>%
  nest_by(var1) %>%
  mutate(resid = list(resid(lm(formula = var2 ~ .-var5, data = data))))%>%
  unnest(c(data, resid))
```

**use group_by + summarize**

```
dat %>%
     group_by(var1) %>%
     summarise(resid = list(resid(lm(formula = var2~.-var1-var5, data =.))),.groups="drop")%>%
     unnest(resid)
```